# Can't stop MongoDB process on CentOS

Tags: mongodb

My OS is CentOS release 6.4 (Final) and my MongoDB version is 2.4.1.

I tried:

```
use admin;
db.shutdownServer()
```

and I got in output:

```
assert failed : unexpected error: "shutdownServer failed: exception: dbexit timed out getting lock"
Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:7)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:6:1)
    at assert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:14:1)
    at DB.shutdownServer (src/mongo/shell/db.js:342:1)
    at (shell):1:4
Thu Apr  7 11:42:52.577 JavaScript execution failed: assert failed : unexpected error: "shutdownServer failed: exception: dbexit timed out getting lock" at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:L7
```

Then I tried to force shutdown, but the output is the same. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

do a command like this

```
ps -ef | grep "MONGO"
```

You will see output like

```
502  8066     1   0 12:23pm ??        12:25.00  /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MONGO/pycharm
```

Now before you do the next command understand that killing a process when it may or may not be doing something is a VERY VERY DANGEROUS habit.

So if this corrupts your MongoDB Database - it is because you did this command.....

```
kill -9 8066
```

8066 is the **2nd** number you can see from the `ps` command.

You can tell if the process is consuming cpu/disk using other systems tools such as

- top
- sar
- instat

If these processes look like the MongoDB Process is doing some work - then the chances of something bad usually increases.

Good Luck !!

Thought: Ask the server to restart ??